# I cannot figure out why my dates don't work

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

```html
structure(list(Position = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = structure(c(1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400, 1685750400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Time
= structure(c(-2209017523, -2209017518, -2209017513, -2209017508, -2209017503, -2209017498, -2209017493, -2209017488, -2209017483, -2209017478), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), DateTime = structure(c(1685808077, 1685808082, 1685808087,
1685808092, 1685808097, 1685808102, 1685808107, 1685808112, 1685808117, 1685808122), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Temperatuur = c(21.2, 21.2, 21.6, 21.7, 22, 22.2, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.3), Treatment = c("Tempex", "Tempex", "Tempex",
"Tempex", "Tempex", "Tempex", "Tempex", "Tempex", "Tempex", "Tempex")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My R code:

```
time.start=as.POSIXct("2023-06-03, 16:00",format="%H:%M")
time.end=as.POSIXct("2023-07-03, 07:30",format="%H:%M")

ggplot(logger, aes(DateTime, Temperatuur, color = Treatment))+
geom_line(size = 1)+
scale_x_datetime(limits = c(time.start, time.end),
breaks = date_breaks("24 hours"),
labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

I just cannot figure out why I am getting this: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4p5e.png)

Can someone please help me?

I tried to follow advice online, but that got me nowhere. Changing from 24 to 12 hours also didn't help. Maybe it's a problem in my excel file, but that all seems alright.

Comment: Can you please `dput(head(logger, 10))` and paste the output into your original question (edit the question, don't add it as a comment) so we can see the data being plotted ?

Comment: The `format` string in `as.POSIXct` specifies the format of the **input** character string. That would be `"%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M"`

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the commas from the `time.*` strings and fix the errant `format=`, it should work.

```r
time.start <- as.POSIXct("2023-06-03 16:00")
time.end <- as.POSIXct("2023-07-03 07:30")
ggplot(logger, aes(DateTime, Temperatuur, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_datetime(
    limits = c(time.start, time.end),
    breaks = date_breaks("24 hours"),
    labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

I think perhaps you are confounding the use of `labels=date_format("%H:%M")` as what you think `time.start`/`time.end` should be (or how they should look), which is incorrect. Since the x-axis is (I'm inferring) a `POSIXt` object, then the `time.*` objects also must be the same object. You don't need to make them "look" (i.e., `"%H:%M"`) the same as how you want the axis labels rendered, it is handled automatically by ggplot.